# Calculating limits with theorem of Lagrange

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> If we know $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }f'(x)=0$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. If we define $g:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(x+2020) - f(x)$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f(2020x) - f(x)$. What can we say about the existence and value of these limits?

I solved the first one with the theorem of Lagrange and became that the value for $x \rightarrow \infty $ was also zero. I tried to do the same for the function h but that did not seem to work because I became $0 * \infty = f'(c)*(2019x)= h(x)$. I also do not know that it is two times differentiable so I am not allowed to use the rule of l'Hospital.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second limit may not exist, for example, choose $f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{x})x^{1/3}$, then $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3} \sin(\sqrt{x})+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\sqrt{x})x^{-1/6}$$
clearly converges to $0$, while
$$\lim f(2020x)-f(x) =x^{1/3} \left(  2020^{1/3}\sin(\sqrt{2020x}) -\sin(\sqrt{x})\right)$$
does not exist because $\sin(\sqrt{2020x}$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$ infinite times.